# Too long if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var deviceName = '';

if(deviceName == 'sampleOne'){
   newName = 'One' 
}

if(deviceName == 'sampleTwo'){
   newName = 'Two' 
}

if(deviceName == 'sampletThree'){
   newName = 'Three'
}
```

I have this simple if statement for Javascript.

How it works?

When a data inputed is `sampleOne` the output will be `One`. That's it, very simple right?

Take note that this code is working fine. But my problem is I have so many sample and I think using this kind of If statement is a bad idea because it will be too long. Is there a way to shorten this if statament?

Comment: you can use `switch case`

Comment: Use `str.split('sample' )[0]`

Comment: Shouldn't we use the triple equals (===) equality comparison operator in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a lot of these  you can make an object that maps the `deviceName` to the `newName`. Then you can just look it up:

```js
let lookup = {
  'sampleOne': 'One',
  'sampleTwo': 'Two' ,
  'sampleThree': 'Three'
}

let deviceName = 'sampleTwo'
let newname = lookup[deviceName]
console.log(newname)
```

Comment: You beat me by 1 min

Answer (score 1):

You can use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement:

```js
var deviceName = 'sampleFour';
var newName;
switch (deviceName) {
  case 'sampleOne':
    newName = 'One';
    break;
  case 'sampleTwo':
    newName = 'Two';
    break;
  case 'sampleThree':
     newName = 'Three';
    break;
  case 'sampleFour':
    newName = 'Four';
    break;
  case 'sampleFive':
    newName = 'Five';
}

console.log(newName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var deviceName  = "sampleOne";
newName =deviceName.split('sample')[1];
console.log(newName );
```

If your value starts with `sample` just use this logic

Comment: *upvoted* nice, I learned something new. But my value doesn't always start with `sample` But still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch statement. Find an example below:

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var deviceName  = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

    switch(deviceName ) {
        case "sampleOne":
            text = "One";
        break;
        case "sampleTwo":
        text = "Two";
        break;
        case "sampletThree":
        text = "Three";
        break;
        default:
        text = "No Match";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Switch instead of IF condition. Switch can be used if you want to do multiple operations in conditions.

```
var deviceName = 'sampleOne';
switch(deviceName)
{
    case 'sampleOne':
        newName = 'One';
        break;
    case 'sampleTwo':
        newName ='Two';
        break;
    case 'sampleThree':
        newName ='Three';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```